# How to replace ~ with /Users/$USER in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

In a bash script, I want the user to enter a path to an application, and then launch that application. By default, the application is expected to be in the user's own directory. The following script works for me on Mac OS X, but it is not particularly elegant:

```
path_default="~/neo4j/bin/neo4j"
read -p "Enter path to neo4j [$path_default]: " path
path="${path:-$path_default}"

if [[ ${path:0:1} == "~" ]]; then
  path="/Users/$USER"${path#"~"}
fi

$path start
```

How can I improve this so that it will work on any platform?

Answer (score 0):

if you consider ~ can be in any platform you can use a variable, for example `userpath=$(echo ~)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
path_default="$HOME/bin/neo4j"
read -p "Enter path to neo4j [$path_default]: " path
path="${path:-$path_default}"
path="${path/#\~/$HOME}"
```

Here, tilde in the beginning of the `path` variable is substituted by the contents of `$HOME` variable.